# Jquery nested context menus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Has anyone managed to find a good jquery plugin for context menus which supports nested context menus and is compatible with all browsers (especially ie and firefox)?

in case anyone who reads might have had a similar issue -
Personally, I will need the context menu to appear when the user right clicks on a table row. hence on right clicking a row, besides displaying the context menu, I also need to enable background selection (i.e. in my case row selection). the reason i am mentioning this is that a particular plugin i have already tried does not allow this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.